# Floating CTA Image Integration

Tags: customization

I want to add a clickable image that links to another page. It also scrolls with the user as they read the article on a page. For example https://bit.ly/2RJ0BZW – like the “U.S Free Local Quote” seen on this page.

If you could provide advice or signpost me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is HTML and CSS, not specific to WordPress so you might get closed as "off topic".  Which part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [Sticky Side Buttons](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sticky-side-buttons/) plugin. Follow these steps:

1. Install and activate the plugin.
2. Head to **Sticky Side Buttons** menu into your WordPress dashboard.
3. Click on **Add Button**. A box will open up, showing the options for
   adding text, icon, link, and color for the button.
4. Under the General Settings section, you will find options for
   **Button Positions**, **Rollover Style** and **Animations**. Choose your desired settings.
5. Finally click on **Save Changes** button.